# GeoLocation API - The difference between the specs & their implementations

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, geolocation, gps

I've just tried on Droid 2.2 & mobile Safari v4.0 build 533.1:

... not even even setting { enableHighAccuracy:true } returns the concrete GPS fix.

Fennec 8.0 works like a charm - on the very same device (results below).

Edit: I don't need the hyperlink to the W3C specs ...

Let me rephrase the question:

**From which version/build of mobile Safari accessing the GPS fix by GeoLocation API is supported (Droid/iPhone)???**

Comment: "native access to hardware" screams "exploit vector" to me, plus it would involve a whole lot of math which I think most people don't want to do. I don't think I've ever had much trouble with the Geolocation API returning inaccurate data, maybe there's another problem here you can solve. How are you testing this? What device?

Comment: A location based on surrounding WiFi is extremely inaccurate, it's giving you a best guess and marking it as such. Is that what you're complaining about? That skyhook-style geolocation isn't as good as GPS?

Comment: What I'm complaining about is that the fix returned from the API is just useless - since it's a few hundred meters of the spot. Also: how about areas without any network coverage... that's fail for sure.

Comment: Well what do you expect? If you're using a device with no GPS, you should be happy you're getting anything at all.

Comment: Im still uncertain what "device" you are using -- the Iphone ask the user for permission for each app... if you are using an iPhone, have you checked if your app have been disabled for location updates?

Comment: It's not even required to access it directly from JS - would be enough if mobile Safari has access - which could be prevented by *LBE Security Guard* (or browser settings), for those who may be concerned. The currently situation is just very unfortunate for cross-platform GPS app development. Workarounds like this one: code.google.com/p/mobile-gps-web-gate are just not native, not nicely portable.

Comment: Android 2.2 Froyo & soon 3.0 - iPhone GPS is crappy, has no z-axis.
Besides I'm talking about cross-platform solutions - so the device shouldn't matter. I mean, the GeoLocation specs are just fail, not any device which implements them.

Comment: I don't want to be a dick but have you actually tested this? I just walked from one side of my office to the other and maps.google.com tracked me the whole way. Not the app, the website. In Mobile Safari. To wit: MOBILE SAFARI HAS ACCESS TO THE GPS. Maybe you don't have GPS reception?

Comment: Why native Java apps have reception then?

Answer (score 3):

You are making an assumption that HTML5 geolocation only uses wifi for location. In fact, devices that have built-in GPS use this GPS for HTML5 geolocation.

[The spec explicitly states this:](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html)

> Common sources of location information include **Global Positioning System (GPS)** and location inferred from network signals such as IP address, RFID, WiFi and Bluetooth MAC addresses, and GSM/CDMA cell IDs, as well as user input.

The device you're testing may not have a GPS, or your web browser may simply not understand how to use it.

If you tell us what device you're testing on, someone may be able to tell you how to get the GPS working properly.

Comment: I can't confirm this:
My Droid (Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.2; en-de; HTC_DesireHD_A9191 Build/FRF91) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1) delivers perfectly exact results in native Java apps - but just useless results with navigator.geolocation in JS. With useless I mean 2 digits after the comma, when enableHighAccuracy:true.

Comment: Should mobile Safari v4.0 build 533.1 support that?

I mean, the specs say "Common sources of location information *include*" ... not that it would check for these sources in the stated order. Of course I've read this before - just reality looks a little different... even when running the script from SD, with HSDPA disabled it won't use GPS.

Comment: I simply won't accept this answer - because it's just copy & paste from Google, about specs that I've read myself days ago. Only real acceptable answer would be how to force navigator.geolocation to read the GPS fix - or at least a list with user-agents and how far they support these specs.

Comment: "*In fact, devices that have built-in GPS use this GPS for HTML5 geolocation.*" - this is definitely not fact - probably rather like someone imagined it to be. Unless implemented, that's not "a fact".

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257160/is-it-possible-to-get-maximal-gps-precision-on-mobile-browser

Comment: I didn't copy anything from Google. That's a serious claim that you can't back up. If your phone doesn't work right that's not my fault. Don't accept the answer, I don't care.

Comment: The specs are just the top hit when entering 'HTML5 GeoLocation API'-
and everything in they gray box is copy & paste for sure. Just got two extremely different results on the very same device - and the phone is not the problem. Will post the results/conclusion later. I might accept your answer in case you'll add your user-agent string.

Comment: haha I'm not going to do any more to help you, I've done nothing but try to help you and you've been combative and insulting. Figure it out yourself.

Comment: Why insulting? Only because I don't accept a search-engine result as a proper answer? Let Me Google That for you? I'm developing software since 20 years - not exactly the noob you've taken me for.
You shouldn't take any professional critic personal - it was never meant like you've probably understood it - sorry.

Comment: @syslogic The grey box is *supposed* to be a quote

Comment: @robertc: I know. (being a web-developer with international clients), but still: I can google by myself, have read this before - and these specs have not too much too do with how widely they have been implemented in the field (specs != facts) - so this answers is not considered as sufficient. It would be nice if the specs would be facts, but in this particular case, this exactly is the problem... as documented below.

Comment: In fact, we are talking about practice - not the theory.

Comment: If you know it's supposed to be a quote, why are you giving him a hard time for having copy & pasted it?  If you don't want to hear about the spec then you should consider rewording your question title so it doesn't mention it so prominently.

Comment: Well, he felt insulted for me not accepting his insufficient answer (which not even answered the initial title of this) - I could have felt insulted for being taken as a noob. Testing with different browsers on the same device was what brought some light to this.

Comment: I even would have accepted the answer - but without the concrete user-agent string of the device he tested with - it's worthless to me.
Just would need to know which version of mobile Safari support access to the GPS fix.